# How many degrees Celsius/Fahrenheit can be reached in 1 square meter area using magnifying glasses?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, reflection, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation

The magnifying glasses are each 10 meters in diameter, their collected light is concentrated via mirrors into a 1 square meter spot. Is it possible to get a temperature higher than 2000 degrees Celsius (3600 degrees Fahrenheit)? Let's say the day is cloudless and the experiment is carried out near the equator.

Bonus question: how long would it take for the area to reach that temperature?

Answer (score 0):

The limit for such a setup is the surface temperature of the source. If it's the sun, then that's 5,600 Celsius. The rate the temperature rises depends on the heat capacity of the material, and any paths of heat loss.